# Can't launch bluemix IOT foundation dashboard on MAC computer?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I tried use browser safari , firefox, Chrome, the dashboard is pending on loading something. I tried from Windows, the dashboard works fine.
I launched the IOTF dashboard from bluemix portal after I login the system.
 
I got from error message from web console .

```
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0001/auth/"
/api/v0001/auth/ <br>
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0001/auth/organizations"
organizations<br>
    TypeError: a is null
    a/<.requestUser/</<()iotui-d....0.0.js (line 10)
    n/j.success/<()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
    i/<()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
    Wb/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 3)
    Wb/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
    Wb/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 3)
    f()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
    r()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
    kb/</g()iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)


    ...ypes.get=function(b){return b?          a.get(c.rest.v2.type(b)):a.get(c.rest.deviceTypes(...

    iotui-d...ndor.js (line 2)
```

Comment: Hello, we are investigating.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The dashboard window opens and is then stuck on the load spinner forever.

Comment: Update: as I didn't have access to a Windows machine, I installed an Ubuntu virtual machine and could access the device dashboard easily. No joy on OS X though - irrespective of browser choice.

Answer (score 0):

Our team is able to load the IoT Dashboard on a MAC. Please check if you are connecting from a country that may have a government network firewall (such as China) if that may be preventing your connection.